# How do I align the image to center in the SVG regardless of changes made to image's width?

Tags: image, svg, alignment, center-align

I tried using css and js to align the image in center but it did not work. The image does not stay aligned in the center if I increase or decrease the width of the image. Please help me with the solution that can align any svg images to the center regardless to their width.

```
<svg style="border:5px solid black" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
        <image visibility="visible" id="header_image" x="45%" y="6%" width="20%" href="https://resources.mynewsdesk.com/image/upload/t_open_graph_image/eyblf65bkcezbnfxfo3n.jpg"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Since width is 20% you may want to use x="40%"

Comment: Thank you but percentage cannot be static because if width or height changes for the image. It won’t be in the center